# Given matrix times vector, find the inverse of the matrix times the same vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inverse

Given $AV= \begin{bmatrix}8\\8 \\ 8 \\8\end{bmatrix}$, where A is a matrix and V is a vector, find $A^{-1}V$.

My thought are the following:

**Step 1:**

Times $A^{-1}$ for both sides.

$A^{-1}AV=A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}8\\8 \\ 8 \\8\end{bmatrix}$

$V=8A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$

$\frac{1}{8} V=A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$

**Step 2:**

Can I assume $AV=\lambda V=8*\begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$ here?  Hence, $V=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$? Is this a correct step?

**Step 3:**

If step 2 is correct, then

$\frac{1}{8}V = \frac{1}{8} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}=A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}=A^{-1} V=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{8} \\ \frac{1}{8} \\ \frac{1}{8} \\\frac{1}{8}\end{bmatrix}$

Does the above inference sounds right?

Comment: If you can find $x/y$ given $xy=8$ (only) then you could solve the stated problem.

Comment: Do you mean there is some missing statement here?

Comment: Take $A$ to be the identity and $V$ the vector $[8, 8, 8, 8]^T$.  Then $A^{-1}V = AV= V$.  However, for $A$ eight times the identity and $V = [1, 1, 1, 1]^T$ you get a different $A^{-1}V$ (the one you computed).

Comment: This seems like an example of the XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no you can't assume $AV = \lambda V$. Not every vector is an eigenvector. Even if $V$ were an eigenvector, then this would still not give you a well-defined answer.

For one example, take $A = I$, the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix. Then $AV = V$, hence $V = \begin{bmatrix} 8 \\ 8 \\ 8 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

As another example, take $A = 2I$. Then $AV = 2V$, hence $V = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \\ 4 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

As you can see, there clearly needs to be more conditions placed on $A$ before this has a clear solution.

Comment: It seems like V has the form $V=constant * [1,1,1,1]^T$. So, can I conclude that $A^{-1} V=c * [1,1,1,1]^T$?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I've just picked scaling matrices to illustrate how the eigenvector assumption doesn't guarantee you the solution. As another example, take $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, V = \begin{bmatrix} 8 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: **What if I add extra information regarding the vector $V$ as the following**,

Question: Given $AV= \begin{bmatrix}8\\8 \\ 8 \\8\end{bmatrix}$, where A is a matrix and **${V=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}}$** , find $A^{-1}V$.



Times $A^{-1}$ for both sides.

$A^{-1}AV=A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}8\\8 \\ 8 \\8\end{bmatrix}=A^{-1} * 8 * V$. Then,


$V=A^{-1} * 8 * V$
We can derive
$\frac{1}{8}V = A^{-1} V=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{8} \\ \frac{1}{8} \\ \frac{1}{8} \\\frac{1}{8}\end{bmatrix}$.

Add information about $V$ seems become a trivial question?

Comment: Yes, that works. You're assuming $V$ is a particular eigenvector with a particular eigenvalue: $8$. Then you can compute $A^{-1} V$ just as you did.

Comment: I thought I am not having any assumptions here. V is just some vector which not necessary be eigenvector to the matrix A. Am I making thus assumption somewhere else?

Comment: Well, you're assuming a value both for $V$ and $AV$. As it happens, they are multiples of each other, and $V$ is non-zero. This is the definition of $V$ being an eigenvector of $A$. I'm just saying, if you fix $V$ and $AV$ in this way, then this implies $V$ is an eigenvector with known eigenvalue $8$. This is what allows you to compute $A^{-1}V$.

Comment: Step1. Times $A^{-1}$ for both sides.
$A^{-1} AV=A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}8\\8 \\ 8 \\8\end{bmatrix}$

Step2: Factor out 8 from RHS of the equation.
$A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}8\\8 \\8\\8\end{bmatrix}=A^{-1}*8*\begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$

Do I have to assume $V$ is the eigenvector to factor out 8 in this step?

Step3: Since $A^{-1}A=I$ and $IV=V$, then
$V=A^{-1}*8*V$

Step4: Divide by $8$ for both sides
$\frac{1}{8}V=A^{-1}V$

Could you point it out which step use eigenvector? Is that Step 2?

Comment: You're not **directly** assuming that $V$ is an eigenvector. You're assuming that $AV = [8, 8, 8, 8]^T$ and $V = [1, 1, 1, 1]^T$. Putting this together, we get, $AV = 8V$, which **immediately implies** $V$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: I don't mean it as a criticism of your solution: given the assumptions you've started with, your reasoning is perfectly valid. I was just pointing out that, underlying it all, what's allowing you to do this is the fact that your assumptions **immediately imply** that $V$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with a known eigenvalue. If you make other, seemingly analogous assumptions, e.g. $V = [1, 0, 0, 0]$, then you cannot proceed, as this means $V$ is not an eigenvector, and there will be many possibilities for $A^{-1}V$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If B=A^-1 and b=<8,8,8,8> then from AV=b you get V=Bb and then BV=(B^2)b. I gess that this is the final result, if there are not other information about A.

Answer (score 0):

**What if I add extra information regarding the vector $V$ as the following**,

Question: Given $AV= \begin{bmatrix}8\\8 \\ 8 \\8\end{bmatrix}$, where A is a matrix and **${V=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\ 1 \\1\end{bmatrix}}$** , find $A^{-1}V$.

Times $A^{-1}$ for both sides.

$A^{-1}AV=A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}8\\8 \\ 8 \\8\end{bmatrix}=A^{-1} * 8 * V$

$V=A^{-1} * 8 * V$

$\frac{1}{8}V = A^{-1} V=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{8} \\ \frac{1}{8} \\ \frac{1}{8} \\\frac{1}{8}\end{bmatrix}$

Add information about $V$ seems become a trivial question?

Explaination:I did not use the assumption that V is the eigenvector of the matrix A here. Just factor out 8 from $[8,8,8,8]^T$ to become $V$.